# MySQL: calculate and update a row with other rows value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Table1

```
ID    X      Y
1     0.5    0.5    
2     ?      ?
3     5      5
```

Hello All,

Basically I have a table just like the one above. Im trying to UPDATE the value of X and Y of ID = 2 with the result of a division of the values of other colums.

I tried running this query without much success,

```
"UPDATE Table1 SET X = X IN (WHERE ID = 1) / Y IN (WHERE ID = 3) WHERE ID = 2"
```

The result that I want would be

```
ID       X          Y
1        0.5        0.6    
2        (0.5/6)    (0.6/5)
3        5          6
```

Answer (score 1):

In many databases, you can use a `JOIN`.  In MySQL syntax, this looks like:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 JOIN
       Table1 t1_1
       ON t1_1.ID = 1 JOIN
       Table1 t1_3
       ON t1_3.ID = 3
    SET t1.X = t1_1.X / t1_3.X,
        t1.Y = t1_3.X / t1_3.Y
    WHERE t1.ID = 2;
```

Similar logic can be accomplished with using subqueries, but the code is a bit messier.